# yahoo finance api problems converting money symbols

Tags: api, yahoo, finance

From years we use http://download.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=USDARS=X&f=l1 to retrieve conversions between money symbols. Since 9/25/2011 retrieve always 0.00.

Any Ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using Google can do the same thing.

http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?EUR

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the .finance in the URL.

http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=USDARS=X&f=l1